# C# Lambda take the records of the latest date

Tags: c#, lambda

I am wondering, if it is possible to get **the records of the latest date** using lambda?

For example:
Assume my records returns something like this:

```
{date: '2017-01-03', unit: 5},
{date: '2017-01-03', unit: 3},
{date: '2017-01-02', unit: 8}
```

Ends up, my query:

```
myService.GetAll()
         .OrderByDescending(a => a.date)
         .??
```

Note that, let say i don't want to perform `group by` first, maybe you might want to say that i could do this:

```
myService.GetAll()
         .OrderByDescending(a => a.date)
         .GroupBy(a => a.date)
         .Take(1)
```

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

Desired output:

```
{date: '2017-01-03', unit: 5},
{date: '2017-01-03', unit: 3},
```

**EDIT 2:**

My original problem: I wrote a logic, if the dates params are null, it would take the latest data. Otherwise it goes to filter.

[image]
[image]

Comment: *let say i don't want to perform group by first* Any specific reasons?

Comment: thanks for asking this. mayb i have something mistaken. If I do 'group by', it will return a IGroup instead. Or is it possible to convert from IGroup to IEnumerable?

Comment: At the end, what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: @un-lucky I just added the expected outputs, basically only those with the latest date. Basically, I just create the service that expose to others, which make me exclude 'group by' from first thought

Comment: "Is it possible?" I don't know -- you wrote the code; *what happened when you ran it*?

Comment: @EricLippert It returns an IGroup (i mean if use group by), originally it returns an IEnumerable

Comment: @zeroflaw - It returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Key, Value>>`. Is that what you mean by `IGroup`?

Comment: I don't understand how your desired output relates to the query you suggested. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes you are right. Sorry I overlook something.
'Can you please elaborate?' Sure. The question is, provided a list of data (with the possibility that one day may contain multiple value), how to return only the records with the latest date? (originally i have 3 records, after query, it returns 2 only)

Comment: You say that you want an enumerable, but you have one.  Your call to `Take(1)` returns an `IGrouping<Key, Value>` which is an `IEnumerable<Value>`, which is what you want.  Why are you asking the question? You know what the answer is. It is very confusing when people ask a question that they know the answer to.

Comment: @Eric Lippert If I already know the answer, why would I need to waste my time to post here? To further clarify the question, the 'myService.getAll()' returns an IEnumerable. But it contains All the records, which I don't want, but I only desire the records of the latest date only. But from my superficial understanding, I only know the 'Group By'. However, the Group By returns an IGrouping, not IEnumerable. I only want to filter the out those not the latest data.

Comment: **A grouping is an enumerable**. Saying that you have a grouping but not an enumerable is nonsensical. What do you think a grouping is if not an enumerable? It is helpful to me to understand why people have false beliefs about programming. Since a grouping is *by definition* an *enumerable sequence of elements in a group*, it is strange to say that it is not an enumerable.

Comment: Ok Great. Now I added 2 more images in the question, showing my original problem faced. If I only do group by and take 1. It shows an error as in the second image. If you can further explain on this, i would really appreciate

Comment: That's a completely different problem; a problem which you have inconveniently made difficult to solve by blocking out the information needed to help you. The problem here is that you've incorrectly re-used the variable `temp` to mean too many things; some of those things are of different types, and that's not legal in C#.

Comment: To help you solve that problem we would need to see all the code where temp is declared and assigned, which you've not shown.  Also, please never post an image of code or errors on SO; post the text.

Comment: I personally think the question is clear enough. First, provided an IEnumerable (stored as temp), I want to get the IEnumerable which contains the latest data. What should I do? The reason I posted this question, is because when I do GroupBy and Take(1), it returns an incompatible type (IGrouping).

Based on the solution, I realized I need another query just to get the date first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres various way to do that. correct me if im wrong, what you need is just a list of data which contains latest date right. 
below one of sample to get your result.

```
   var res = myService.Where(p=>p.date == myService.OrderByDescending(a => a.date).SingleOrDefault().date).ToList();
```

Comment: That looks workable. Since you're ordering to get the comparison date, why not `.takeWhile()` on the ordered enumerable?

Comment: @RichardMatsen could you please elaborate more on the .takeWhile(), i would like to know more. Thank you

Comment: If you move OrderByDescending outside the Where, save it to a variable, you can find the first date and TakeWhile on ordered with the same comparison. Sorry for the syntax, I've being doing lots of rxjs.

Comment: Where is fine, but if the list is long I'd expect TakeWhile to be a little more efficient.